# 4 level deep of For loops for counting objects

Tags: c#, unity3d

I'm just going to ask about this 4 Level Deep For Loop of Mine though i put it inside of the `StartCoroutine();`

Here is my code : *please don't judge me yet*

```
void Update()
{
    if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.BLOCK_GAME_FLOW == false)
    {
        CameraScriptsAir_1 = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(2).GetChild(0).gameObject;

        CameraScripstAir_2 = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(2).gameObject;

        //get the Camera with Bloom Script
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCameraScriptTV; i++)
        {
            CameraScriptsTV[i] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(i + 5).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        }

        //get the Camera With DepthOfField Script and Bloom Script
        TwoScript[0] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(8).GetChild(0).GetChild(1).gameObject;
        TwoScript[1] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(38).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;

        //9 - 11
        //get only the depthoffield.cs
        for (int j = 0; j < maxTests1; j++)
        {
            Tests1[j] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(j + 9).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        }

        //get all the Test with the camera Bloom script
        for (int k = 0; k < maxTests2; k++)
        {
            Tests2[k] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(k + 12).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        }

        //get the fog GameObject
        FogEffect = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(2).GetChild(0).GetChild(2).gameObject;

        if (!foundAllComponents)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CountObject());
        } else
        {
            StopCoroutine(CountObject());
        }
    }


    if (foundAllComponents)
    {
        if (OptionPopup.isCheckedCamera == true)
        {
            CameraScriptsAir_1.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = false;
            CameraScriptsAir_1.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
            CameraScripstAir_2.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = false;
            CameraScripstAir_2.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;

            foreach (GameObject camScriptTV in CameraScriptsTV)
            {
                camScriptTV.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
            }

            foreach (GameObject two in TwoScript)
            {
                two.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = false;
                two.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
            }

            foreach (GameObject test in Tests1)
            {
                test.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = false;
            }

            foreach (GameObject test in Tests2)
            {
                test.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CameraScriptsAir_1.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = true;
            CameraScriptsAir_1.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = true;
            CameraScripstAir_2.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = true;
            CameraScripstAir_2.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = true;

            foreach (GameObject camScriptTV in CameraScriptsTV)
            {
                camScriptTV.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = true;
            }

            foreach (GameObject two in TwoScript)
            {
                two.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = true;
                two.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = true;
            }

            foreach (GameObject test in Tests1)
            {
                test.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = true;
            }

            foreach (GameObject test in Tests2)
            {
                test.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = true;
            }
        }

        if (OptionPopup.isCheckedFog == true)
        {
            FogEffect.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            FogEffect.SetActive(true);
        }
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log("Wait for the component to be found!!");
    }

}

IEnumerator CountObject()
{
    //count the object inside the camera objects
    for (int i = 0; i < CameraScriptsTV.Length; i++)
    {
        //count the object inside the twoscript objects
        for (int j = 0; j < TwoScript.Length; j++)
        {
            //count for tests1 objects
            for (int k = 0; k < Tests1.Length; k++)
            {
                //count for tests2 objects
                for (int l = 0; l < Tests2.Length; l++)
                {
                    //check all the objects if they're not null
                    if (CameraScriptsAir_1 && CameraScripstAir_2 && FogEffect != null && CameraScriptsTV[i] != null && TwoScript[j] != null && Tests1[k] != null && Tests2[l] != null)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("GameObject is not null");
                        foundAllComponents = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Lets wait for the game object to be attached");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

On the last part of my code

```
IEnumerator CountObject()
{
    //count the object inside the camera objects
    for (int i = 0; i < CameraScriptsTV.Length; i++)
    {
        //count the object inside the twoscript objects
        for (int j = 0; j < TwoScript.Length; j++)
        {
            //count for tests1 objects
            for (int k = 0; k < Tests1.Length; k++)
            {
                //count for tests2 objects
                for (int l = 0; l < Tests2.Length; l++)
                {
                    //check all the objects if they're not null
                    if (CameraScriptsAir_1 && CameraScripstAir_2 && FogEffect != null && CameraScriptsTV[i] != null && TwoScript[j] != null && Tests1[k] != null && Tests2[l] != null)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("GameObject is not null");
                        foundAllComponents = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Lets wait for the game object to be attached");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

This one is just for counting of my object so that i can put it inside an if else statement . I could not compare an Array of GameObject to null if i'm not going to get its Length right ? So is my way of doing it is safe or not? and did i use my coroutine right cause i'm a bit conscious of it. I'll accept any discrimination on my code.

Comment: Just about your last snippet: are you just testing `CameraScriptsTV.All(NotNull) && TwoScripts.All(NotNull) && ...`? You can write it like that (where `static bool NotNull(object obj) => obj != null;`). Also you're returning an `IEnumerator` but `yeld return` generates an `IEnumerable<T>` and...there isn't any enumeration there. What for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going to log an awful lot of "GameObject is not null" items, for very few non-null game objects.

Basically, you've made an O(n * m * p * q) algorithm, where all you needed was (at most) an O(n + m + p + q) algorithm. This would achieve the same effect - beyond the fact that you'll get fewer logs of the same non-null combination over and over again.

This code assumes that the library requires an enumerator.

```
IEnumerator CountObject()
{
    if (CameraScriptsAir_1 &&
        CameraScripstAir_2 &&
        FogEffect != null &&
        CameraScriptsTV.Any(e => e != null) &&
        TwoScript.Any(e => e != null) &&
        Tests1.Any(e => e != null) &&
        Tests2.Any(e => e != null))
    {
        foundAllComponents = true;
        Debug.Log("GameObject is not null");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Lets wait for the game object to be attached");
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some very general comments:

I would suggest that the code needs to be more readable, because for someone who is not familiar with it - it’s difficult to discern what is going on.

- You can immediately improve the code just by **giving better names** for variables/methods. What is tzPlayInfo? What is its instance?
- Why are we getting the children of children of children: `this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(2).gameObject;` - surely there’s a better way? What is `gameObject` - can you think of a more descriptive name. Also this looks like it's **violating the law of demeter** (please google it if you're not familiar with it.)
- There are way too many if statements for it to be understandable - so perhaps **rethink the algorithm**.
- I recommend **breaking up the code into many separate methods** - i.e. a good rule of thumb, as an exercise, would be to make each method no more than 10 lines long. This will force you to break things up. Right now it's a wall of code/text.
- Typically folks would return an `Enumerable<T>` rather than an Enumerator – is there any reason why an enumerator is returned?
  **- Avoid deep nesting**. It could take a very long time as N increases.

Answer (score 1):

- Why do you need to return an enumerator? It's only useful if you `yield return` items to make a list. Here you just return `null` which is the same as returning `true` or `false`.
- Why do you need the nested loop? What are you trying to do? Right now when each of the lists first item is not null, you already set the variable `allFound` to `true` but you keep on looping. So if the next item is `null`, you still set it to `allFound`. Seems strange.
- Naming. `GetChild().GetChild()`. Much easier to read as `GetTest()`. It's also known as a "train wreck", all the nested `GetChilds`. One solution is to have a method in the top class return all the data you need.